# Transition to previous route on error action ember.js

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-cli

I have the following situation to handle in ember :-

1. I have to transition to a route which has a model hook. The model hook returns a promise. (Say route A -> route B, Route B has a model hook returning a promise)
2. While the model hook in B is running, the loading route is entered(for showing "please wait" type msg to user).
3. In case the model hook in B fails, I need to transition back to route A. I handle the error action in route B.

The problem is, while handling error action in route B, the previous route is not always route A. It can be from other another route too.

I tried the possible workarounds, but they didn't work out for me:-

1) Using window.history.back() - This fails because Route B isn't entered yet, because the model hook promise failed. So I get the previous route of Route A.

2) Using this.controllerFor('application').get('currentRouteName') - This gives the loading route (While transitioning from Route A to Route B, intermediate route 'loading' is rendered).

I can use a conditional check with query Params, but I feel this is not efficient as I have to check for many conditions.

I simply wish to return to the route that invoked Route B.

Pardon me if I missed out on anything.

Answer (score 0):

Sample project : [Twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com/00dbf8ab5c5f0553bb21?numColumns=1)

I reopened `Ember.Route` to catch all transitions and save the current route name in a application controller property. When `error action` is called, i transition to the route saved in that property. Routes with dynamic segments will need extra handling.

Another Method :

In your router.js,

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  didTransition : function(infos){
    this._super(infos);
    var appController = this.container.lookup('controller:application');
    var crn = infos[infos.length - 1].name;
    if(appController && crn!=='loading' && crn!=='error'){
      Ember.set(appController,'myRouteName',crn);
    }
  }
});
```

I am not sure if there is any in built solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. This workaround works good for my case. But is there any in-built solution in Ember itself for this?